# Airdrop cost optimization

Tags: solidity, erc-20, crowdsale, airdrop

I am planning an airdrop of an ERC20 mintable token created through a crowdsale contract based on [Open Zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts).

Now what I am wondering, is what would be the cost effective way of adding an airdrop functionality. Here's what I could think of:

- Send all tokens reserved for the airdrop to the crowdsale's owner wallet on contract creation and then write a small Node.js + Web3 + ethereumjs-tx app that simply loops through the list of airdrop wallets and sends to each one of them some tokens (wallet to wallet) using `sendSignedTransaction`.
- Add an airdrop method to the Crowdsale contract that will receive the array of wallet addresses and loop through those, `mint()`ing and transferring the tokens to each of them. Then call that method through Node.js + Web3 passing it the list of addresses?

Is there a better way that I am missing?

What would be cheapest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 is the more commonly used. Instead of paying the a fee for every transfer you group together several transfers.

A different approach is to have a "virtual" airdrop where only events are generated and the actual balances are acredited on the first transfer.

But you should write the code and test yourself.

Comment: but in method 2 lets say i pass 100 addresses to the method, i would still need to make 100 transfers, so i would still pay a fee for every transfer, right? or am i missing something?

Comment: Making two transfers in a single transaction should be cheaper than making two transfers in two transactions. But in any case you should not trust me, program the two solutions and mease the gas used.

Comment: ok i see, and what about the virtual airdrop, not sure i understand what you mean that the balances are credited on the first transfer. what first transfer?

Comment: The idea is to only generate Transfer events, that should be cheap because contract storage is not modified. Wallets and/or block explorers will show the balance from the Transfer event. When someone asks for a balance you will check if the account was initialized, if not initialized return a fixed value. The accounts will be initialized when they make their first transfer, when they call transfer or tranferFrom from the contract.

Comment: What purpose would such an airdrop serve ?

Comment: @NikitaFuchs Airdrops are used for different purposes: ICOs, marketing, paying customers/users, distributing profits, etc. An important issue is to minimize the costs associated with it and making a better use of the Ethereum network. IMHO we may not like airdrops but there's no way to _prohibit_ them, so it is better to look ways to make them more efficient.

Comment: @Ismael I meant the purpose of suggesting the user that he received tokens whereas he actually did not, through the usage of event triggering

Comment: @NikitaFuchs The idea is to have a _virtual_ balance that is only initialized when it is used.

Comment: But to be able to use it, there will have to be another transaction which actually grants that balance to the user?

Comment: @NikitaFuchs The idea is to only initialize the balance when a transfer is executed.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Function calls don't have access to data from previous events, so the user definitely can't initialize it himself.

Comment: @NikitaFuchs The balance is updated when you call `transfer()`, my use case was when every user was initialized with the same amount.

Comment: Aaaaaah, gotcha.